# Random Fourier series in Hilbert space

Tags: pr.probability, harmonic-analysis

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and $X_n$,
$ n\in \mathbb {Z}$, be a sequence of independent Bernoulli random variables
$P(X_n = \pm 1) = \frac 12$. Is there a characterization of the sequences
$a_n$, $ n\in \mathbb{Z}$, in $H$ such that the series
$$
    \sum_n a_n X_n e^{int}, \quad t \in [0,2\pi],
$$
is almost surely uniformly convergent in $H$?

Comment: Did you look in J.-P. Kahane’s book, Some Random series of functions. I believe this will contain answers to your question.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there's nothing in Kahane's book about that, not even a characterization of scalar sequences.

Comment: @DangZheng That's partially wrong: there is no *full* characterization (for the simple reason that it is still unknown) but there is a whole chapter on when the sum of a random Fourier series with scalar coefficients is almost surely continuous and the continuity is actually derived from the uniform convergence.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a full characterization for scalar sequences in the work of Marcus and Pisier (1981) via entropy integrals. The vector-valued case is an application of a deep result on Bernoulli processes (Bednorz-Latala, Annals of Mathematics 2013).